# bool tools remove the entire object disappears

Tags: modeling, modifiers, faces

I'm trying to extract the handle above from the object itself but I'm only left with a couple of faces from one object only
[image: this is the face beofre the bool]

and this is what happens after adding the differnce bool tool :
[image: after adding the bool tool]

the two objects are normal and all the transformations have been applied
[image]

Comment: the bool tools are known to be unstable and sometimes cause issues. can you share your file so we can find some workarounds. my workarounds are sometimes to use union instead of difference then manually delete the faces.

Comment: yeah sure will share it right away https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fiETf6UtC2LpVH-q9Pj0GWUAoCSH6RDQ/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

Your bucket model has overlapping geometry as seen below as a dirty orange color which can cause issues when using the boolean modifier. Go to *Edit Mode* and press <kbd>A</kbd> then press <kbd>M</kbd> *> Merge by Distance*. This removes around a thousand overlapping vertices. Then you can apply the boolean difference again and it will work.

[image]

[image]

Comment: thanks a million harry deadline is tomorrow and you just saved my life thank a lot man

Comment: cool glad i was able to help!